# What are the uses of static function in multi-threaded and kernel programs?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel

In the last interview, I got a question like "What are the uses of static functions in multi-threaded program and kernel  programs?". I answered that the function cannot call from outside of that file so we can reuse the same function names in another files. And EXPORT_SYMBOL is used to give access to outside in kernel programs.

But he was not happy with this. Is there any other uses when we come to multi-threading and kernel code?

Comment: I can't think of any relationship between static functions and multi-threading.

Comment: I often see that using a `static void *` function (instead of plain `void *` function) as the argument to `pthread_create` as good practice.  To prevent people calling it by mistake, and, in case it is needed somewhere else, be passed as a pointer to function.  But that is really about it, am not even sure whether it is argued as good practice in the pthread docs (the example in `man pthread_create` certainly uses a `static void *` function though)

Comment: You will often use static variables in the start_routine so that they can easily be shared by all of the threads.  This often implies that the start_routine is a static function.

Comment: Perhaps the interviewer's key point was that a static function can't be called from another source file, not that another source file could use the same function name. I'm not sure how this relates to multi-threading, since c functions are inherently re-entrant and can be called from multiple threads as long as those functions don't contain any "non-protected" static variables.  In the "old days", functions were declared as static to reduce linker symbol table overhead and build times, although if doing a debug build, static names still go into the debug info.

Comment: Another point about static functions is that a compiler can perform "global" optimizations on a source file, since there are no external (to the source file) references to a static function. Again, this would be unrelated to multi-threading, as you could use a single source file for multiple threads.

Comment: Thankyou all for your valuable comments. What about in the case of kernel code?